# Debugging cron tasks in WordPress

Tags: debugging, wordpress, cron, logging

How could I debug cron task run by internal [cron functions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Category:WP-Cron_Functions)? My cron task is not firing and I suppose some functions are not declared yet when cron hook takes place.

It would be great if I can store the errors into some log file? Any ideas? Thanks.

I used Core Control plugin to see if everything is all right. The *my_task_hook* and hooked function too, the "due time" is changing...so something else must be wrong.

Comment: I am using the functions category_exists and post_exists which are declared for "wp-admin" only. This was the problem.

I found out the easiest way to debug cron in WordPress is add your function to this hook: add_action( 'sanitize_comment_cookies', 'your_cron_function' ); because wp_cron function is also executed in this action hook. You will see errors outputted (if there are any) after doing this when you reload your front-end page.

Answer (score 1):

I found the 
wp-cron dashboard plugin
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-cron-dashboard/
very helpful. Using it I was able to see what cron tasks were working or not.

I also found that the docs on the cron functions weren't very clear. 
When setting up a wp cron task make sure you add the function as an action using add_action only then can you run wp_schedule_event on the task.

Good luck!

Comment: The plugin looks interesting. Thanks for the tip ;)